# Why do awk split() make first field to be last element in array?

Tags: awk

I'm probably missing something really simple here, but when I say

```
echo 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.' | \
    awk '{
        split($0, WORDS, " ");
        for ( WORD in WORDS ) {
            print $WORD;
        }
    }'
```

I get this in return:

```
quick
brown
fox
jumped
over
the
lazy
dog.
The
```

Why is the first word printed last?

```
$ awk --version
awk version 20070501
```

Comment: bug in your awk? doesn't happen here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, `for (i in array)` in `awk` yield the index of array, not the array elements. So you got the result like you accessed `$1`. `$2`... `$NF`.

```
echo 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.' | \
    awk '{
        split($0, WORDS, " ");
        for ( WORD in WORDS ) {
            print WORD;       
        }
    }'
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
1
```

You can see you got array indexes when accessing variable `WORD`.

---

For your question, POSIX defined looping through `awk` array yielding the array index in [unspecified order](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_09):

> for (variable in array)
>
> which shall iterate, assigning each index of array to variable in an
>   **unspecified order**.

So it's up to implementation to define *how* to traverse the array.

A quick test in my system shown that `gawk` and `mawk` looping with increasing order:

```
for AWK in gawk mawk /usr/5bin/[on]awk /usr/5bin/posix/awk; do
  printf '==%s==\n' "$AWK"
  echo 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.' |
  "$AWK" '{
    split($0, WORDS, " ")
    for (WORD in WORDS) {
      print WORD;
    }
  }' | { sed 1q; tail -n1 }
 done
==awk==
1
9
==mawk==
1
9
==/usr/5bin/nawk==
2
1
==/usr/5bin/oawk==
2
1
==/usr/5bin/posix/awk==
2
1
```

(With GNU `sed`, you need `sed -u 1q`)

Answer (score 6):

You're not printing the elements of the array, you're printing the fields in order. In `awk`, variables are not prefixed with a `$`, that's fields. So, `$a` will print the field of whatever number is stored in `a`. To print a variable, say `foo`, you need `print foo`, no `$`.

When you iterate over an `awk` array, you are iterating over the array's indices:

```
$ echo 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.' |     awk '{
        split($0, WORDS, " ");
        for ( WORD in WORDS ) {
            print WORD;
        }
    }'
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

What you were after was:

```
$ echo 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.' |     awk '{
        split($0, WORDS, " ");
        for ( WORD in WORDS ) {
            print WORDS[WORD];
        }
    }'
The
quick
brown
fox
jumped
over
the
lazy
dog.
```

Which, in GNU `awk`, is equivalent to:

```
 $ echo 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.' |     awk '{
            for (i=1; i<=NF;i++){
            print $i
        }
    }'
```

---

While `gawk` (GNU `awk`) `split` will sort the array in the order it was found (as shown above), other implementations don't do that as cuonglm explains in his answer. Therefore, instead of using `split`, you can set the field separator and let `awk` to the splitting. In your example, there's no need to since the separator is a space, but here's how to do it for other cases:

```
 $ echo 'The-quick-brown-fox-jumped-over-the-lazy-dog.' | 
    awk -F"-" '{
                 for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
                    print $i
                 }
                }'
The
quick
brown
fox
jumped
over
the
lazy
dog.
```

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring the fact that in your example, you could (should) just print each field `$1`, `$2`, etc., `split` returns the number of elements in the array, so to loop through them in the order they appeared you can use something like this:

```
echo 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.' | \
    awk '{
        n = split($0, WORDS, " ");
        for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            print WORDS[i];
        }
    }'
```

As others have mentioned, the order of traversal through an array when using `for (indx in array)` is unspecified (although you can control it if you're using GNU awk).