# Sum values in 5th column that correspond to same field in 2nd column

Tags: text-processing, awk

Considering below file:

```
0,2,,,10
0,2,,,15
0,1,,,984
0,2,,,9
1,14,,,5
```

Using `awk`, I need to calculate the total value in `$5` per each `$2`.

The desired output would look like below:

```
2,34
1,984
14,5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
awk -F, '{a[$2]+=$5};END{for(i in a)print i","a[i]}' <file
```

A note that [array traversal in POSIX awk is unspecified order](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/219631/38906).

Answer (score 2):

With `gnu` [`datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
datamash -t ',' -s -g 2 sum 5 <infile
```

the output will be sorted by 2nd column:

```
1,984
14,5
2,34
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd be tempted to use perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %things;

while (<>) {
    my ( undef, $key, @rest ) = split(/,/);
    $things{$key} += pop(@rest);
}

foreach my $key ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %things ) {
    print "$key = $things{$key}\n";
}
```

You could condense that down to a one liner if needs be.