# merge content of two files with summing the content of column 2?

Tags: text-processing

I have a following data in a 2 file:

file1

```
apple,2
orange,1
grapes,4
pear,8
```

file2

```
apple,1
grapes,2
orange,4
```

How do I post process the two files to get the following?

file3

```
apple,3
grapes,6
orange,5
pear,8
```

Comment: Just `cat` the files and pipe the result to any of the solutions posted here: [Sum values in Nth column that correspond to same field in Mth column](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/222128), adjusting the field numbers accordingly...

Answer (score 6):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F, '{x[$1]+=$2} END{for(i in x) printf("%s,%d\n", i, x[i])}' file1 file2 | sort > file3
```

which uses associative arrays in `awk`.